# Is loss prevention able to enter a dressing room while someone is changing?

Tags: privacy

I am a a fashion stylist in Los Angeles, CA. I often go to stores and shop for clients (and myself). Last year, I spent 100k at a Neiman Marcus.

Recently, a loss prevention person and an over zealous female salesperson entered my dressing room before I was finished trying on clothes. The male accused me of stealing, which I did not. Even with that, I attempted to make a $7500 purchase and they denied my purchase. I contacted the store manager. At first, she seemed shocked. Then she must have talked to someone, because she called me back and said, “loss prevention is allowed to enter dressing rooms”.

How can they get away with this? This is, at the least, defamation and at the most, bias. What do you think?

Comment: If your question is: Is there a [California statute](https://www.shouselaw.com/invasion-of-privacy) that prevents a member of the opposite sex from entering the dressing room, even if they have cause as they  are loss prevention?  If it is, then rewording your question is more likely to get a meaningful response.   Fortunately, there are plenty of other better places to shop in LA.

Comment: It would be very difficult to prove that you intended to steal anything in the dressing room, since you wouldn't yet have had an opportunity to pay for it.

Answer (score 2):

I would ask the manager to "see the tape" (recording).   If there is indication that a device was used to observe you in the fitting room and come to the conclusion that you were engaged in theft, then [there may be a case of invasion of privacy](https://www.shouselaw.com/invasion-of-privacy):

> 1.1. Penal Code 647(j)(1) – using a device to look through a hole or opening
>
> It is an invasion of privacy under Penal Code 647(j) (1) to:
>
> Look through a hole or opening into, or otherwise view:
>   The interior of any area which someone is occupying with a reasonable expectation of privacy, including any:
>
> - bedroom,
> - bathroom,
> - changing room,
> - **fitting room,**     <=======================
> - dressing room, or
> - tanning booth
>
> By means of an instrument such as a:
>
> - periscope,
> - telescope,
> - binoculars,
> - camera,
> - motion picture camera,
> - camcorder, or
> - mobile phone;
>
> With the intent to invade the privacy of a person or persons inside.
>
> An exception is areas of a private business used to count currency or other negotiable instruments.